# In declaring properties for a polymer element, why is value sometimes a function that returns {}?

Tags: javascript, polymer

The part I'm curious about is why use

```
value: function() { return {}; }
```

instead of

```
value: {}
```

Here's the sample code:

```
<script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'polymer-demo',

      properties: {
        data: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
            value: function() { return {}; }
          }
      },

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is explained in the [example](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values):

> When initializing a property to an object or array value, use a function to ensure that each element gets its own copy of the value, rather than having an object or array shared across all instances of the element.

Although you can use `{}`, this will be the same object shared by each element, so that if the value is mutated for one element, all other elements would see the same change applied to it. This is not what you want to happen. By using a function, the function will be called for each element, and each call will produce a new, separate object. Then a mutation will only apply to that single element without affecting the others.

Answer (score 2):

I feel it is the same reason that `vuejs` requires their `data` component to be rendered as a function rather than the object that it is:

> In the basic examples, we declare the data directly as a plain object.
>   This is because we are creating only a single instance with new Vue().
>   However, when defining a component, data must be declared as a
>   function that returns the initial data object. **Why? Because there will**
>   **be many instances created using the same definition. If we still use a**
>   **plain object for data, that same object will be shared by reference**
>   **across all instance created!** By providing a data function, every time
>   a new instance is created, we can simply call it to return a fresh
>   copy of the initial data.

Thus, making sure that the data being given to the component is always indicative of a fresh "load"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done in cases where you want to show, that you can not only return a fixed value but calculate a dynamic value and return this instead but you were to lazy to return something more than {}. And sometimes the things you are declaring a used in some place by the framework and are there expected to be a function returning an object, and not just a fixed value or object.

You can find out by changing the code, executing it, and watching for errors or different behaviour.